# how to create custom autocomplete textfield in yii

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, yii

I am new to yii. I need to write custom yii auto complete.I knew that CJuiAutocomplete is there.but I need to implement own custom auto complete. can anyone pls guide me or help me to develop custom autocomplete textfield. taking the id while displaying name in the textfield.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's wrong with the CJuiAutocomplete? It's quite customisable.

Comment: its fine though..i could not be able to make it work..here is my old link (http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/38924-yii-cjuiautocomplete-values-are-not-getting-displayed/page__p__187066__fromsearch__1#entry187066 ..however for broader search i need custom one keeping in view performance a issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an action in site controller...

```
public function actionAutoComplete($term){

    $query = Yourmodel::model()->findallbyattributes( array('somecolumn'=>$term));
    $list = array();        
    foreach($query as $q){
        $data['value']= $q['id'];
        $data['label']= $q['name'];

        $list[]= $data;
        unset($data);
    }

    echo json_encode($list);
}
```

and here is a search form in your view:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'searchform',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'action' => '/'
)); ?>

    <fieldset>
        <div class="input-append">
        <?php

        echo CHtml::hiddenField('selectedvalue','');

         $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
            'name'=>'searchbox',
            'value'=>'',
            'source'=>CController::createUrl('/site/autoComplete'),
            'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'fold',         
            'minLength'=>'2',
            'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                        $("#searchbox").val( ui.item.label );
                        $("#selectedvalue").val( ui.item.value );
                        return false;
                  }',
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'onfocus' => 'js: this.value = null; $("#searchbox").val(null); $("#selectedvalue").val(null);',
            'class' => 'input-xxlarge search-query',
            'placeholder' => "Search...",
            ),
            ));
            echo '<button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>';   

        ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>    
</form>
```

Comment: this showing [] ... why ? is there anything missing ?? please reply

Answer (score 0):

Because of this condition

```
array('somecolumn'=>$term)
```

it will show results only if you write full string. For example, you have ['coffee', 'cake']. When you type in search box it wont show results for coff, cof, co, ca, cak etc. only will show results if you enter full word coffee, you will get ['coffee'] as result.

So you need something like:

```
$match = $_GET['term'];
$tags = Tags::model()->findAll(
   'tag_name LIKE :match',
   array(':match' => "%$match%")
);
```

This will show results for coff, cof, co, ca, cak etc.