# Yii autocomplete matches from beginnig of the word

Tags: yii, autocomplete

I'm using the CJuiAutoComplete widget for autocomplete user entries inside a form.
Therefore I have a list with some cities. Is it possible to show only values, where the entry matches from the beginnig of the word?

An example:
When typing "ha" inside the field I get

- Ahausen
- Badenhausen
- Bremerhaven
- ...

But I need something like this:
 - Hagen
 - Hannover
 - Halle
 - ...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to do could be to increase the minimum requirement to 3 or more characters. That way you will get fewer entries, and closer to what you require. This is obviously a hack, but should improve things a fair bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for auto complete question in that link. You can edit the query with using "like"...

[how to create custom autocomplete textfield in yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197669/how-to-create-custom-autocomplete-textfield-in-yii/14206748#14206748)